# How to sync Staging folder of XCode project with www folder in Ionic v1?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I am new to ionic so I built a simple project and run on iPhone device.

But when I changed some code snippet, but Staging folder of XCode project is keeping old code.

So I removed old by **ionic cordova platform rm ios** and installed again.

But this way is not comfortable for me.

is there a good way to figure out this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Staging" in Xcode is where the asset files are located in the native project i.e. `/platforms/ios/www` whereas "www" in Xcode is the asset folder in the Cordova project i.e `/www`.

When you run `ionic cordova prepare ios` it copies the asset files from `/www` to `/platforms/ios/www` (Staging).